# How to access AuthController?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

As I need to apply custom login to AuthController ( adding a public method that will be called to alter the protected $redirectTo )

I can alter the access scope for $redirectTo, however, I don't want to break the framework.

So, how can I access AuthController ? isn't it singletone class?

Comment: you can use your custom methods, in `Auth controller` what the issue ?

Comment: you can use the `redirectPath` as per your requirement, as changing them doesnot means that your breaking the framework flow. Laravel just give you and example that what and how you can do

Comment: I need to access my custom method in AuthController from inside an event listener, Something like Auth::conroller()->setRedirect("new-path") for example..

Comment: still not getting your point... please explain with example

Comment: I just want to access the instance of AuthController from any where in Laravel, is that possible?

Comment: eg: you have controller named `LoginController` type this on top `use App\Auth\AuthController;` then create object of authcontroller and try it.

Comment: But, I want to access the current active AuthController that laravel is currently using while registering a user..

Comment: why you are doing this ? if you are trying custom things, then you should use separate controller

Comment: How to tell laravel to use the new controller instead of the AuthController?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you are not using Laravel default `AuthController` then In routes you can tell/specify about the custom controller for your login/logout and register. here is the example

```
Route::get('/user/login',                   ['as'=>'user-login','uses'=>'Login\LoginController@getLogin']);
Route::post('/user/login',                  'Login\LoginController@postLogin');
Route::get('/user/logout',                  ['as'=>'user-logout', 'uses'=>'Login\LoginController@getLogout']);

// Registration routes...
Route::get('/user/register',                'Login\LoginController@getRegister');
Route::post('/user/register',               'Login\LoginController@postRegister');
```

**Note**

> Login\LoginController, 1st Login is `Login` directory same as `Auth` directory while 2nd one is `controller` same is AuthController